# New compiler warning in iOS 5 SDK about initializing with incompatible pointer types

Tags: objective-c, ios, types, compiler-warnings

This statement

```
drawTimebar *drawView = [drawTimebarView initWithFrame:drawTimebarView.frame];
```

was working just fine in iOS 4, but with the iOS 5 SDK gives a warning:

> Incompatible pointer types initializing 'drawTimebar *' with an expression of type 'UIView *'

Why has this changed, and what can I do to solve it?

Comment: As a side note, your class names should *always* be capitalized. It is standard convention in obj-c.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that stands out is that you are declare the variable as `drawTimebar` but initializing and assigning a `drawTimebarView`.

Answer (score 3):

First, Class names should always begin with a capital latter and be CamelCased. This helps others read your code and helps you keep track of instances versus classes.

Second, you are declaring that `drawView` is an instance of `drawTimeBar` (presumably this is a class, so it really should be `DrawTimeBar`) with this bit

```
drawTimebar *drawView
```

However, when you initialize the pointer, you are creating an instance of `drawTimeBarView` (presumably also a class, and hence should be `DrawTimeBarView`) with this bit

```
[drawTimebarView initWithFrame:drawTimebarView.frame];
```

The warning is letting you know that you are inconsistent. My guess is that you really mean to have

```
drawTimebarView *drawView = [drawTimebarView initWithFrame:drawTimebarView.frame];
```

Comment: Another point is that there's something wrong with `[drawTimebarView initWith...]`, although what exactly isn't clear. It's either a poorly-named class method with an incorrectly-capitalized class name, or an invalid initialization of a (probably) not-allocated instance. Or...?

Comment: Hey PengOne, thanks for your answer but unfortunately it doesn't work. I'll try to explain what i'm doing here. I used some code scraped from the internet so forgive any mistakes or convention errors. drawTimeBarView is an UIView in my parent view and drawTimeBar is the class of this view. I'm trying to initialize this class so i can draw something in drawTimeBarView. It works fine, but it just gives this error in XCode. Don't really understand whats going wrong. Regards